# What's the difference between "adduser" and "useradd"?

Tags: linux, debian, user-management

I wonder: Why are there these two commands on Debian Linux, with very similar names and functionality? This has always been confusing for me.

- Is any of them superior to another?
- Why aren't they merged into one?
- Is there any significant difference between them?
- Which one should I use? Or does it depend on a use case?

Comment: Note that `useradd` is available on all Unix-like platform; `adduser` is only for Debian and its derivatives.

Comment: [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org) uses [BusyBox](https://busybox.net) which only has [`adduser`](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#adduser). `useradd` is only [available](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/post-install.html) if the [shadow](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=shadow&branch=edge) package is installed.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`useradd` is native binary compiled with the system. But, `adduser` is a perl script which uses `useradd` binary in back-end.

`adduser` is more user friendly and interactive than its back-end `useradd`. There's no difference in features provided.

Comment: adduser isn't available on all distros (eg. suse-based), and on some others  it's just a symlink to useradd (redhat-based).

Comment: `adduser` provides an option `--disabled-password` while `useradd` doesn't. But I guess that `useradd` can do the same using a different option or combination of options (like `--inactive` or something like that).

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan "adduser provides an option --disabled-password while useradd doesn't". There is no need; the password is already disabled by default. From <https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/passwd/useradd.8.en.html>: "-p, --password PASSWORD The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.". The more usual way to set the password (outside of Debian at least) is to use `passwd` (i.e.: after `useradd`).

Answer (score 17):

The main advantage to **adduser** over **useradd** is dealing with system level users. With **adduser** the system level users account when created puts a user directory in home for the system user where **useradd** does not automatically. If you read the man they are essentially the same except for system level users and associated  home directories are automatic. **adduser** creates a /home/user directory automatically for system level users where there is not a provision in **useradd**, except if specified by **-m** option. The other readings I have come across generically state that UID and GUID are assigned by accepted conformal Debian standards in **adduser**.

Comment: adduser has a --no-create-home option.

Answer (score 5):

In a couple of Redhat instances I checked (4.9 from 2011 and 6.9 from 2017), adduser is simply an alias to useradd, not a Perl script. Here it is in Redhat 6.9:

```
$ ls -la /usr/sbin/useradd /usr/sbin/adduser
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      7 Nov  2  2016 /usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd
-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 111320 Feb  9  2016 /usr/sbin/useradd
```

The way I remember that useradd is the 'correct' program is this: adding a user is just one operation in the CRUD spectrum. You also need 'modify' and 'delete' operations ('read' is presumably covered by viewing /etc/passwd). And so, the programs are named *user** (useradd, usermod and userdel respectively). I suppose the alternative **user* naming convention (adduser, moduser and deluser -- these don't exist) could also work. But it would be slightly more awkward (for a reason I cannot express clearly at the moment :)

Comment: can't find `moduser` on Debian, but `deluser` is definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

One significant difference I ran into (and did not see in an answer here), is that `useradd --system` seems to imply `--shell /bin/bash`, while `adduser --system` implies `--shell /usr/sbin/nologin`, which is what I wanted.

But I also wanted *no home directory* (which is the default with `useradd` but not with `adduser`), so I could either use **useradd** like this

```
useradd --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin foo
```

(or `/bin/false` is also popular for *no shell*)

Which leads to e.g. the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
foo:x:994:991::/home/foo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Or use **adduser** like this

```
adduser --system --no-create-home foo
```

Which leads to e.g. the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
foo:x:110:65534::/home/foo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Note that there are also very different automatic assignment of (G)UIDs. `useradd` seems to pick them counting downwards from 999, while `adduser` counts updwards from 100 for the UID and uses 65534 for the GUID (which seems to mean *no group*). In fact, `useradd` also creates a group (see `/etc/group`), while `adduser` doesn't.

So for me, I will stick with **adduser** having learnt all those facts.

Source: Tested on Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Buster based).

Answer (score 0):

Within raspian (I would need to check for other OSs), 'adduser USER' starts a dialog (TUI) while 'useradd USER' does NOT.

Apparently, using adduser, once the dialog comes up, the full 'useradd' command is already executed. Even if you CTRL-C your user is there.

As in the new systems they create "personal" groups, to remove the newly created user you would need to:

- vi /etc/passwd
- vi /etc/group
- rm -rf /home/USER

I assume that because adduser "uses" useradd, the rest is metadata about the user.
So technically no changes in "skel", "file masks", or the like, i.e. your system defaults.

On the other side, because useradd does not bring up any TUI, it might be more useful in
scripting.

To be honest I tested it only in rasbian, because that was the reason I stepped on the question.

I can imagine that other OSs might implement a different version of adduser.