# Is there any way to find and create multiple users in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Want to create multiple user in Linux, but first need to check user already exists or not,if not exist the user get created.

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried?

Comment: Some Linux distributions have `adduser` or `useradd` commands. See eg [useradd(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/useradd.8.html) and [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)

Comment: And, more importantly, which information about those users do you have, and in in what form is it presented?

Comment: If not a duplicate, this question already have many answer! Try `man adduser` in a console, in your system, and have look at https://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "adduser" and "useradd"?](https://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/newusers

It will allow you to create new users in batch from a file.

Comment: The command to add a new user is distribution dependent and also the question states how does the Masoom check if a user exists before creating.  This partly answers the question.